How to wrap custom post type array in an unordered list using PHP for Wordpress? Having difficulty with my CSS not working
After a fair few years of using HTML and CSS i've finally decided to give PHP a go and build a Wordpress Theme for myself. I have setup a custom post type with the slug 'work' which is linked to a 'Work' page. I have successfully retrieved the 'posts' inside of my 'Work' post type and also have these linking to the correct post by retrieving the permalink. However, I am struggling to wrap each post thumb in a LI, wrapped in a UL and then reference this in my CSS.
After looking through multiple threads on here I have managed to get to where I am now but am stuck. I have referenced other answers and structured as others have however, when I reference the div class or ID in my stylesheet it is not changing the styling of the post thumbs.
<?php
/*
Template Name: Work
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>


    <section>
        <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'work', 'posts_per_page' => '12' ) );?>
            
        <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            
            <div class="work-content">
                <ul>                        
                    <li> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">

                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                
                        <div class="thumbnail_title">
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="thumbnail_services">
                            <h4><?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'service' ); ?></h4>
                        </div>

                        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                            echo $term->name;
                        }
                        ?>
                        
                    </a></li>
                            
                </ul>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
        
    </section>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>


Not directly related to your problem, but if you have a CPT with a slug of work, WordPress will automatically attempt to use a page called archive-work.php, so you don't need to create a custom query. Maybe you have a reason to do it this way, but I just wanted to point that out. On the archive-work.php you'd then use the native loop and get pagination for free, too. Inside of the loop, you'd still ultimately have the same problem you are facing right now.

Thank you, I hadn't realised. As I say, i'm new to PHP and this is my first attempt at building myself a custom template.

We all start somewhere, and I'm glad you are diving in and learning!

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to add a <ul> between the if and while loop, and then inside the while loop, wrap each item in an <li>.
<?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <ul class="work">
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li class="single-work">
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

I'll note that some people really hate this "template" syntax, and although I was one of them in the past I've really grown to love it. If you do continue to use it, I would generally encourage you to do it line-by-line. So open a <?php, write you code, then close it with ?>, all on the same line. Some people really hate that, however I think the performance issues are moot in modern PHP, and even if there was an issue, in the grand scheme of things for a WordPress site it shouldn't be measurable compared to other things that can be optimized.

That's done the trick!! Thank you very much. As I say, i'm very new to this. Much apprecaited.
